# Wide to Long Format in R - Pre- and Post-test with Multiple Questions

Tags: r

I am trying to prepare my dataset to run a HLM on it. Right now, the dataset is in wide format, so I need to change it to long format. I've tried using the `reshape` function, but to no avail so far. There are 51 pre-test questions and 51 post-test questions. The original format of the dataset is similar to this (this is just for one individual):

```
Student.ID  PreTest1  PreTest2  PreTest3  ...  PostTest1  PostTest2  PostTest3
   2322        3          2         5               2          4          5
```

Ideally I want the final dataset to look something like this:

```
Student.ID  time  Score  Question
   2322       1     3       1
   2322       1     2       2
   2322       1     5       3
   2322       2     2       1
   2322       2     4       2
   2322       2     5       3
```

Is this possible to do in R? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `melt`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), `melt` from 'wide' to 'long' format, then create the 'time' and 'Question' variables after grouping with the substring of the variable (by removing the numeric part with `sub`).

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.var = "Student.ID", value.name = "Score")[,
   c("time", "Question") := .(.GRP, 1:.N) , .(sub("\\d+", "", variable))
  ][, variable:= NULL]
#   Student.ID Score time Question
#1:       2322     3    1        1
#2:       2322     2    1        2
#3:       2322     5    1        3
#4:       2322     2    2        1
#5:       2322     4    2        2
#6:       2322     5    2        3
```

---

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df, Var, Score, -1) %>% 
     separate(Var, into = c("time", "Var2"), sep = 3) %>% 
     group_by(time = match(time, unique(time))) %>% 
     mutate(Question = row_number()) %>%
     select(-Var2)
#  Student.ID  time Score Question
#       <int> <int> <int>    <int>
#1       2322     1     3        1
#2       2322     1     2        2
#3       2322     1     5        3
#4       2322     2     2        1
#5       2322     2     4        2
#6       2322     2     5        3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Student.ID = 2322L, PreTest1 = 3L, PreTest2 = 2L, 
PreTest3 = 5L, PostTest1 = 2L, PostTest2 = 4L, PostTest3 = 5L),
 .Names = c("Student.ID", 
"PreTest1", "PreTest2", "PreTest3", "PostTest1", "PostTest2", 
"PostTest3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: Hi, Akrun--thanks for your reply. I'm looking at your code for the data. I have 51 pre-test questions and 51 post-test questions. Is there an easier way to insert the names? Perhaps I can do `.Names = names(df)[c(1, 9:59, 61:111)]`? (1 corresponds to the variable `Student.ID` and columns 9-59 are the 51 pre-test variables and 61-111 are the 51 post-test variables).

Comment: @user122514 where do you want to insert the names?

Comment: Since you labeled the variables individually in your code (where it says `.Names = c("Student.ID", 
"PreTest1", "PreTest2", "PreTest3", "PostTest1", "PostTest2", 
"PostTest3")`), I was wondering if there was a less tedious way to list all 103 variables.

Comment: @user122514  Oh, no, I didn't do it.  It is the output of `dput` after we read the dataset in R.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Let me try to make some sense of the code and see whether it works for my dataset. I have over 200 variables, so hopefully I don't encounter that many errors! Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, Akrun. Another question. Of course the dataset I supplied is just an example. My actual dataset has other variables, like Last Name, First Name, etc. How would I be able to keep these variables and their corresponding values after switching from wide to long format?

Comment: @user122514 You can use the `id.var = c("id", "Last Name", "First Name")`

Comment: Ah, double-checked my output. For some reason, the `time` variable has three values--1, 2, 3--which is weird because there are only two time measurements. Any idea what could've gone wrong? I've only made small changes to your code: `melt(setDT(calSWEC), id.var = c("CalSWEC.ID", "Intern_Last_Name", "Intern_First_Name", "Year"), value.name = "Score")[, c("time", "Question") := .(.GRP, 1:.N) , .(sub("\\d+", "", variable))][, variable:= NULL]`

Comment: @user122514  Can you check whether there are any leading/lagging spaces in the column names?

Comment: Re: Nevermind--it was a mistake on my part. I forgot to include one important variable in the id.var parameter. It works perfectly. Thanks again for everything.